# Issus with $.post Jquery and styles on HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've got a basic jquery script returning some HTML for me in. The code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){

    $.post('libraries/content.php', function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The script returns the html that is kept in content.php, but it doesn't apply any styling to it.

Basically, I've a link that says "show more content", which shows a drop down list that is kept in content.php (the php script populates the drop down that's why it's in a separate file), but I've no idea why the drop down is not styled.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Gregor

Comment: your code seems alright. inorder for us to help you, please do one of the following:           a. post your relevant stylesheet           b. try checking the newly added html style using firebug style inspector, maybe you'll find out something u missed...

Comment: Where and how do you define styles? And which styles? (since styling available on dropdowns is quite limited)

Comment: There's 8 style sheets! I define the stylesheet in all.css (and import them) which is linked in the head of the document.

Comment: Also, if I include the HTML that is in content.php directly into the page then is styles fine. It's only when I'm trying to load it through the script above

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.
Example:

```
$("#content").load("libraries/content.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

when you say dropdown you mean a `<select>` element?

if you are using a webkit browser (google chrome, safari) then the styling of `<select>` boxes is not a fun thing to do.

to ensure this is the problem just copy the output of `content.php` in your original file and see if it is styled when not loaded dynamically. 
i suspect you will see the same problem.

another way to verify this is by adding `background-color:blue;font-size:30px;` to the `<select>` field's style (webkit needs combinations of styles, only changing the font-size will be ignored).

and a third way to verify: test it in firefox. it takes styles on form fields more seriously.

Comment: p.s. open this page in safari/chrome to see how sometimes css styles on dropdowns are simply ignored: http://particletree.com/examples/safari3/drop.html

Comment: The styling I have on the drop down works on all browsers (ie7+, FF and all the webkit browsers). I develop in FF.

Comment: hm... not what i expected then. 
can you narrow down your problem so it runs in jsfiddle.net? 
(you can do a $.post to a different domain there without problems)